# Issue populating Symfony3 Request ParameterBag when using Guzzle and FOSRestBundle

Tags: php, symfony, guzzle, fosrestbundle

We are currently using the following..

- PHP 7.0
- Symfony 3.1.3
- Guzzle 6.2.1

Within a Symfony command we are building a JSON request which gets sent back to an API endpoint (in the same application) and the code looks like this...

***TestCommand.php***

```
        $client = new Client(['verify' => false, 'query' => ["api_key" => $this->api_key]]);
        $uri = $this->router->generate('order_create', [], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);


        $request = new Request('POST', $uri, ['headers'=>['content-type' => 'application/json']],
            json_encode([
                'userId'=>$basket->getUserId(),
                'store'=>$basket->getStore(),
                'locale'=>$basket->getLocale(),
                'billingAddress'=>$basket->getBillingAddress()->getId(),
                'shippingAddress'=>$basket->getShippingAddress()->getId(),
                'currency'=>$basket->getCurrency(),
                'coupon'=>$basket->getCoupon(),
                'utmSource'=>$basket->getUtmSource(),
                'utmMedium'=>$basket->getUtmMedium(),
                'utmTerm'=>$basket->getUtmTerm(),
                'utmContent'=>$basket->getUtmContent(),
                'utmCampaign'=>$basket->getUtmCampaign()
            ]));

        $response = $client->send($request);
```

The method that receives this request looks like this...

**TestController.php**

```
  class TestController extends FOSRestController{
    /**
 * Creates a new order and returns its meta information.
 * @param Request $request
 * @ApiDoc(
 *   resource = true,
 *   section = "Order Operations",
 *   statusCodes = {
 *     200 = "Returned when successful",
 *     500 = "Returned when we are unable to create a Order"
 *   },
 *  parameters={
 *      {
 *          "name"="store",
 *          "dataType"="string",
 *          "required"=true,
 *          "requirement"="DE | CH | EU | AT",
 *          "description"="What is the store the Order is coming from."
 *      },
 *      {
 *          "name"="locale",
 *          "dataType"="string",
 *          "required"=true,
 *          "requirement"="DE | EN",
 *          "description"="What is the Orders locale."
 *      },
 *      {
 *          "name"="billingAddress",
 *          "dataType"="integer",
 *          "format"="12 | 334",
 *          "required"=false,
 *          "description"="the id of an AppBundle\Address entity to use as the billing address."
 *      },
 *      {
 *          "name"="shippingAddress",
 *          "dataType"="integer",
 *          "format"="12458 | 65845",
 *          "required"=false,
 *          "description"="the id of an AppBundle\Address entity to use as the shipping address."
 *      },
 *      {
 *          "name"="coupon",
 *          "dataType"="string",
 *          "format"="eg: 50OFF, VATERTAG20",
 *          "required"=false,
 *          "description"="the coupon that has been redeemed with this Order."
 *      },
 *      {
 *          "name"="utmSource",
 *          "dataType"="string",
 *          "format"="eg: SEO, NEWSLETTER, DISPLAY",
 *          "required"=false,
 *          "description"="the UTM source of this Order."
 *      },
 *      {
 *          "name"="utmMedium",
 *          "dataType"="string",
 *          "format"="eg: Plista, Reichweite",
 *          "required"=false,
 *          "description"="the UTM medium of this Order."
 *      },
 *      {
 *          "name"="utmTerm",
 *          "dataType"="string",
 *          "required"=false,
 *          "format"="RasierKlingen, Razorblades.",
 *          "description"="the utm term of this Order to identify keywords used in your ad."
 *      },
 *      {
 *          "name"="utmContent",
 *          "dataType"="string",
 *          "format"="eg: crm_alpha_upsell_a, crm_alpha_upsell_b",
 *          "required"=false,
 *          "description"="the utm content, helpful for A/B Testing."
 *      },
 *      {
 *          "name"="utmCampaign",
 *          "dataType"="string",
 *          "format"="DISCRITDE, COPERFNETDE",
 *          "required"=false,
 *          "description"="the utm campaign - OLD ICODE."
 *      },
 *      {
 *          "name"="currency",
 *          "dataType"="string",
 *          "format"="EUR | CHF | GBP | USD",
 *          "required"=false,
 *          "description"="The currency of this Order - should one not be set EUR will be selected."
 *      },
 *      {
 *          "name"="userId",
 *          "dataType"="integer",
 *          "format"="1233 | 5512",
 *          "required"=false,
 *          "description"="If this Order belongs to an existing user then this should be their user_id."
 *      },
 *      {
 *          "name"="paymentToken",
 *          "dataType"="integer",
 *          "format"="123 | 22344",
 *          "required"=false,
 *          "description"="the payment token that is to be used in recurrence of this order."
 *      }
 *  }
 * )
 *
 * @Annotations\Post("/",name="order_create",defaults={"_format" = "json"})
 * @return Order
 * @throws \Exception;
 */
public function  postOrderAction(Request $request)
{
        $params = $request->request->all();
        *some other code...*
}
```

}

The issue that we are having is that in our development environment (OS X) $request->request->all(); is populated with the request parameters but when we deploy to our staging server the parameters are not being populated and the ParameterBag is completely empty.

Could anyone give me a pointer in what the issue could be?

note: we've checked that the PHP and vendor versions match and the only difference we can see in our setup is that in our local dev env we use Apache but on our staging env we use NGINX.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Check rewrite rules on nginx, I had similar problem with hiawatha. All looks like works, but it work unless parameters be like: `somepath?param=""`. I had this rule: `Match .* Rewrite /app.php`, and if I added one more before: `Match /(.*)\?(.*) Rewrite /app.php?$2` everything go smooth. If you can, translate it into nginx rules and check results.